# Identifying empty list in JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json data set I'm trying to insert into a database. To do so, I need placeholders "" for non-existent data. In the example below, if there's no email address, I need the insert statement to be (....,"boo",....) instead of (....,"me@mail.com",....). I have tried checking for list length, using not, email == [], etc. Every way I know how or have Googled, and none are working.

Example data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "campsites": {
                ...
            },
            "contacts": {
                "emailAddresses": [],
                "phoneNumbers": []
            },
...
```

My code for this particular section:

```
results = response.json()['data']
for item in results:
    for email in item['contacts']['emailAddresses']:
        if email == []:
            print("boo")
        else:
            print(email['emailAddress'])
```

The if statement (regardless of how I've tried so far), does not execute, and I get a printed list of only the email addresses if they exist:

```
GRSM_Smokies_Information@nps.gov
CATO_superintendent@nps.gov
dyanna.threeirons@crow-nsn.gov
ozar_campground_operation@nps.gov
orpi_information@nps.gov
ozar_campground_operations@nps.gov
biso_information@nps.gov
chis_information@nps.gov
info@antelopepointmarina.com
```

I need:

```
boo
GRSM_Smokies_Information@nps.gov
CATO_superintendent@nps.gov
dyanna.threeirons@crow-nsn.gov
ozar_campground_operation@nps.gov
orpi_information@nps.gov
ozar_campground_operations@nps.gov
biso_information@nps.gov
boo
chis_information@nps.gov
info@antelopepointmarina.com
```

Comment: `if emails := item['contacts']['emailAddresses']: for email in emails ... else: print("boo")`

Comment: `item['contacts']['emailAddresses']` is the list, so `for email in item['contacts']['emailAddresses']` will give you each item in the list ... if the items are strings then `if email == []` doesn't make sense.  Your `if` statement should be outside the for loop, instead of inside it, and should check that `item['contacts']['emailAddresses']` is not an empty list.  @Olvin Roght gives a nice compact version of that above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of `"emailAddresses"` is empty, the for loop doesn't get executed. Accordingly `print("boo")` neither.

You need to check the list first, before iterate through the list:

```py
results = response.json()["data"]
for item in results:
    emails = item["contacts"]["emailAddresses"]
    if emails:
        for email in emails:
            print(email)
    else:
        print("boo")
```